# How do I grab a specific section of a stdout?

Tags: grep, cut, tail

I am trying to grab the `sda#` of a drive that was just inserted.

`tail -f /var/log/messages | grep sda:`

Returns: `Mar 12 17:21:55 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1133.736632]  sda: sda1`

I would like to grab the `sda1` part of the stdout, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use this with GNU grep:

```
| grep -Po 'sd[a-z]+: \Ksd[a-z0-9]+$'
```

---

> \K: [This sequence resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously matched characters are not included in the final matched sequence.](http://www.phpfreaks.com/blog/pcre-regex-spotlight-k)

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)